# How to filter elements in dictonary with ansible/jinja

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a dictionary in ansible/jinja:

```
{
    some_key: some_val
    ...
    remove_me1: some_val
    remove_me2: some_val
}
```

Now I want to create a dictionary, that is identical but with all elements, who's key start with "remove_" removed.

Can this be done using ansibles/jinjas internal filters? Or do I need to write my own filter?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this

```ansible
{{ your_list | reject('search','remove_') | list }}
```

Comment: How is this an accepted answer? This will give a list of keys from original dictionary, not reduced dictionary.